# Convertir json en json multidimensional

Tags: c#, json

Tengo un JSON con la siguiente estructura:

```
[
    {"Model":"6"},
    {"Title":"tituloM6","Value":"saddsaf"},
    {"Title":"msgOperadorM6","Value":"sdafdsfa"},
    {"Title":"msgErrorM6","Value":"sadsdafdf"},
    {"Title":"ok","Value":""},
    {"Title":"imgM6","Value":""},
    {"Model":"6"},
    {"Title":"tituloM6","Value":"asdsf"},
    {"Title":"msgOperadorM6","Value":"asdsddf"},
    {"Title":"msgErrorM6","Value":"dsafsfdsfda"},
    {"Title":"ok","Value":""},
    {"Title":"imgM6","Value":""}
]
```

Pero no logro transformarlo en uno multidimensional con la siguiente estructura:

```
[
    {"Model":"6"},
    {"datos": 
        [
            {"Title":"tituloM6","Value":"saddsaf"},
            {"Title":"msgOperadorM6","Value":"sdafdsfa"},
            {"Title":"msgErrorM6","Value":"sadsdafdf"},
            {"Title":"ok","Value":""},
            {"Title":"imgM6","Value":""}
        ]       
    }

    {"Model":"6"},
    {"datos": 
        [
            {"Title":"tituloM6","Value":"asdsf"},
            {"Title":"msgOperadorM6","Value":"asdsddf"},
            {"Title":"msgErrorM6","Value":"dsafsfdsfda"},
            {"Title":"ok","Value":""},
            {"Title":"imgM6","Value":""}
        ]
    }   
]
```

El json lo obtengo de un `List<string>` y lo convierto con:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lista);
```

He tratado de realizarlo con un foreach que recorriese los elementos de la lista y con dos `List<>`, una para Model y otra para los otros campos y despues unirlas de la siguiente manera:

```
List<string> modelos = new List<string>();
List<string> valores = new List<string>();
bool primero = false;    

foreach (var resultado in result)
{
    if (resultado.Model != null)
    {
        modelos.Add("Modelo");
        modelos.Add(resultado.Model);
        if (primero != false)
        {
            modelos.AddRange(valores);
            valores = new List<string>();
        }           
    }
    else
    {
        valores.Add(resultado.Title);
        valores.Add(resultado.Value);
    }
    primero = true;
}
```

¿Cómo puedo generarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No tienes que deserializarlo a List sino que deberias hacerlo a una class que mapee con esos datos, si usas

http://json2csharp.com/

seria algo como esto

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

entonces usando [json.net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) que agregas con nuget

```
List<RootObject> datos= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
```

al tener la lista podrias aplicar linq para agrupar

Lo que si no veo es como se relacionan los `Title` con el `Model`, si es por la posicion lo veo complicado ya que no podras aplicar un `group by` de linq

Nota: adigna el nombre de la clase as representativo, lo que uses es solo a modo de ejemplo